# How can I disable a particular key of keyboard using python

Tags: python, keyboard

I need to disable a specific key on the keyboard using python so that whenever I will press it, it won't be shown no matter where I type, whether on python shell or in notepad.
Does anyone has any way to do it??

Answer (score 2):

A little late, however if someone stumbles on this:

If you want a specific key to be blocked no matter what, you can use the `keyboard.block_key('key')`
You can do something like this example (this is an example for the a key, but by using the `in` check, you can add as many keys as you want.:

```
import keyboard

def on_key_press(event):
    if event.name in ('a') and not pressed_keys[event.name]:
        keyboard.block_key(event.scan_code)  # Block the key press

keyboard.on_press(on_key_press)  # Register the callback function for key press

# Keep the program running
while True:
    pass
```

Keep in mind that if you want to unblock the key later on you should use `keyboard.unblock_key('key')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard library:

First install with pip:
`pip install keyboard`

Now in your python script

```py
import keyboard
key="f" #The key you want to block
keyboard.block_key(key)
```

Comment: key 'f' is not getting blocked through this snippet.